# Run an NGC Container in VS Code on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, nvidia, ptvs, nvidia-docker

I need to run a Python script within an [NVIDA GPU Cloud (NGC) container](https://docs.nvidia.com/ngc/ngc-getting-started-guide/index.html) on Docker in Ubuntu and I want to use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to edit, run and debug it. I have installed the [VS Code Docker Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/docker) and read the documentation but none of it seems to fit my purpose.

I have followed the [NGC docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/ngc/ngc-titan-setup-guide/index.html), installed the  NVIDIA Container Runtime for Docker (nvidia-docker2) and am now at the point where on the command line I would launch an NGC container tarball

```
docker load -i  foo.tar
sudo docker run {...}
```

How do I configure VS Code so that I can run and debug Python scripts within this container?

Comment: Nice question, I'll try to create a repo showing an example, but the questions are how to:

1. Configure Dockerfile to run the script in debug mode

2. Connect VS Code Debugger with container once running.

I'll make a second Dockerfile that just runs the script in debug mode, in debug mode I'll configure to run the container using --network host (a docker-compose would be better but complex) and remember to build both images before debugging to make sure that you are running the latest

Comment: This one just use Python Extension https://github.com/DonJayamanne/vscode-python-samples/tree/master/remote-debugging-docker ( Disclaimer: I didn't try it but it looks that it has the right idea )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the [NVIDA GPU Cloud (NGC)
   container](https://docs.nvidia.com/ngc/ngc-getting-started-guide/index.html).

Create */home/bob/foobar.py* in [Visual Studio
   Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [VS Code Docker
   Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/docker)

```
import ptvsd
import time
ptvsd.enable_attach(address = ('0.0.0.0', 5678))
ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
time.sleep(2)
print("all righty then")
```

Set a breakpoint on the last line.

Debug|Add Configuration

Docker: Attach to Node

In *launch.json* add to "configurations"

```
{
   "name": "Python Attach (Remote Debug ptsvd default)",
   "type": "python",
   "request": "attach",
   "pathMappings": [
       {
          "localRoot": "/home/bob", // You may also manually specify the directory containing your source code.
          "remoteRoot": "/home/bob" // Linux example; adjust as necessary for your OS and situation.
       }
    ],
            "port": 5678, // Set to the remote port.
            "host": "0.0.0.0" // Set to your remote host's public IP address.
},
```

Open a Terminal window:

```
$ docker load -i foo.tar
$ docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nvidia/cuda           9.0-base            9dcd7cd95db6        2 weeks ago         135MB
nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda   latest              506c995952d1        7 weeks ago         2.74GB    

$ docker run -p 5678:5678 latest    

root@deadbeef: python -m pip install --user --upgrade ptvsd
root@deadbeef: python foobar.py
```

Start the debugger with configuration "Python Attach (Remote Debug ptsvd default)". It stops at the breakpoint.